WildFly always returns the 404 Not Found
Whatever I do, WildFly returns the 404 code to me
I'm using Java 22.0.1, Intellij Idea and WildFly 32.0.1.Final.
I also tried to run similar and working projects with GitHub on this configuration, but I ran into the same problem
I have created a simple Maven project with the following files:

pom.xml:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.sosnilosm.manager</groupId>
    <artifactId>task-manager</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>task-manager REST-API</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- So maven doesn't require web.xml.tmp -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


JaxRsApplication.class:

package ru.sosnilosm.manager.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {
}


TestController.class:

package ru.sosnilosm.manager.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/test")
public class TestController {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}


project structure:
project structure

Nevertheless, when making a request via Postman at the URL http://localhost:8080/task-manager-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/test, I always get a 404 Not Found
Postman results
where did I go wrong?

WildFly 32.0.1.Final - Jakarta EE 10
Project Tree:
war_jax-rs_task-manager
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── ru
        │       └── sosnilosm
        │           └── manager
        │               └── controller
        │                   ├── JaxRsApplication.java
        │                   └── TestController.java
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.sosnilosm.manager.controller</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax-rs-task-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JAX-RS (Java API for RESTful Web Services) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>task-manager</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

JaxRsApplication.java
package ru.sosnilosm.manager.controller;


import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(TestController.class);
        return resources;
    }
}

TestController.java
package ru.sosnilosm.manager.controller;


import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class TestController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testName(@QueryParam("zipName") String zipName) {
        return "test - " + zipName;
    }
}

Package
mvn clean package

Wildfly web console install
target/task-manager.war
Test

http://127.0.0.1:8080/task-manager/api/test?zipName=1234

Note that wildfly 32 supports jakarta ee 10, so the related package names are changed to jakarta.xxx.

From import javax.ws.rs.GET;
TO   import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;

